# how to build skia for ios

Tags: ios, skia

I try to bulid skia on ios.And I down load it then run SampleApp on the mac os.So I want to use it on ios.But when I open the xcodeproj,there are so many files unexits in the project!So what can I do with it and How to build skia for ios??
Thank you for Advance!!

Comment: Build and run sample successfully following this [How to check out and build skia on ios.](https://sites.google.com/site/skiadocs/user-documentation/quick-start-guides/how-to-check-out-and-build-skia-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

The commands below worked for me, this trick is to instruct the (curious) build process not to look for dependencies on the build machine:

```
[ -d depot_tools ] || git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
[ -d skia ] || git clone https://skia.googlesource.com/skia.git

export PATH="${PWD}/depot_tools:${PATH}"
cd skia
python tools/git-sync-deps
gn gen out/Release --args="is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_icu=false skia_use_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_libwebp=false extra_cflags_cc=[\"-frtti\"]"
ninja -C out/Release skia
```